# Retirar palavras reservadas de SQL de uma string Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Estou a fazer uma *view* que tem um campo aberto (`textarea`) onde o utilizador pode escrever SQL e depois pode executar o mesmo SQL.

A questão é que o user oracle onde ele vai correr o SQL têm permissões para tudo e não é suposto ele fazer `delete`'s ou `truncate` ou `insert`. Só é permitido consultas (`select`).

Não estou a ver outra maneira senão ter as palavras mapeadas em memória e verificar se a string contém essas palavras reservadas.

Alguma ideia de como resolver de outra forma?

Answer (score 4):

## Usando uma conexão somente leitura

A única forma totalmente segura de fazer isto e a mais simples também, é criar um segundo usuário no Oracle com permissões somente para leitura das tabelas e então executar essas consultas numa conexão diferente das demais consultas do sistema.

O único trabalho que você vai ter é modificar um pouco a estrutura do programa para permitir isso, talvez configurar um segundo *data source* no seu servidor de aplicação e assim por diante.

## Criando uma sublinguagem a partir do SQL do Oracle

Esta alternativa é bem menos segura e bem mais complicada.

Consiste em criar um interpretador de SQL (praticamente um compilador) que faz a análise léxica, sintática e semântica e assim permite apenas a sub linguagem do SQL que você definir. Tudo o que tiver a mais, fora dessa sublinguagem, seria acusado como um erro de sintaxe do código, ainda que seja um SQL válido.

Essa proposta é viável se você tem proficiência para definir a gramática para uma linguagem formal (prestou atenção na aula de compiladores da faculdade?) para implementar ou gerar um *parser* e se o usuário estaria contente em ter acesso a um conjunto limitado de funcionalidades, afinal tudo o que você não incluir na sua sublinguagem não pode ser usado, mesmo que o Oracle dê acesso.

A boa notícia é que não é difícil reusar algo que outros já fizeram. Uma biblioteca muito conhecida no Java, chamada [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/), é capaz de gerar um *parser* com base numa linguagem formal e existem [várias gramáticas disponíveis para download, inclusive PL/SQL](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql).

Agora, basta você remover da gramática aquilo que não quer. Você vai precisar entender o que está fazendo, então ainda precisa lembrar um pouco daquelas aulas de compiladores.

Com a gramática pronta, você gera o parser. Ao ser executado, o parser interpreta o código (SQL neste caso) e gera uma AST, que é uma árvore com os tokens encontrados.

No seu caso, você não precisa fazer nada com essa árvore, apenas verificar se a interpretação da sublinguagem SQL ocorreu com sucesso.

## Filtro de conteúdo usando uma "lista negra"

Filtrar o SQL usando uma lista de palavras proibidas vai muito além de `delete` ou `insert`. Você precisará incluir qualquer comando que possa:

- Alterar a estrutura do banco
- Alterar configurações do banco ou da sessão
- Eliminar dados e tabelas, como `truncate`
- Executar funções ou procedimentos com efeitos destrutivos
- A lista continua...

Existem procedimentos no Oracle capazes de executar comandos SQL arbitrários se o usuário possui as permissões para isso.

Talvez seja perfeitamente possível chegar a um nível razoável de segurança, mas o problema  disso tudo é que pode acabar filtrando um SQL válido por acaso, um falso positivo, caso algum nome de campo ou tabela ou string contenha o nome de um comando bloqueado.

Não vou deixar aqui porque eu sei que não conseguiria compilar algo totalmente seguro e não quero incentivar essa prática e indiretamente causar precedentes de segurança por aí.

No entando, eu diria que o melhor caminho é olhar o manual do Oracle, pois lá tem todos os comandos e a sintaxe de cada um bem explicadas. Portanto, basta consultar um a um e adicionar os que você não quer que sejam executados numa lista.

Depois que tiver a lista, basta iterativa sobre ela e verificar se alguma palavra está contida no SQL. Na comparação, n ao se esqueça de ignorar maiúsculas e minúsculas e também de considerar a codificação de caracteres.

## Implementando segurança usando medo

Uma alternativa seria avisar o usuário que os comandos digitados serão armazenados e se ele for pego fazendo algo de errado vai perder o emprego ou ser processado.

Claro que isso é uma brincadeira.

O que eu diria é que seria uma boa prática armazenar quem digitou o que, independente da abordagem escolhida. Segurança também inclui investigar ataques maliciosos.

Outro princípio é que, dependendo do uso do sistema, por exemplo se ele for usado internamente por um no úmero limitado de pessoas, não vale a pena investir em algo elaborado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, sim foram as duas possibilidades a questão é que a primeira não depende de mim, penso que não será possível. Achas a verificação de string removendo palavras reservadas como insert, delete, etc.. falível ? Muito insegura ?

Comment: @user2989745 Para usar algum tipo de "lista negra de palavras" você vai precisar de muito mais que duas ou três palavras. Precisa evitar que o usuário crie e execute funções ou procedimentos, qualquer alteração na estrutura das tabelas, alteração de variáveis e configurações no ambiente, além de uma série de comandos que podem ser destrutivos como truncate.

Comment: sim, tem que ser uma "lista negra de palavras" algo extensa, é de longe a pior hipótese, Outra questão da opção de criar uma conexão só para leitura é que tenho que inserir numa tabela o sql final. Corro sempre o risco de injection ou outro tipo de ataque.

Comment: @user2989745 quanto a políticas da empresa ou se depende de você ou não, acho que você precisa rever isso. Como uma pessoa técnica, você não pode assumir que as coisas são do jeito que são e precisam continuar assim. Depois se houver algum problema o culpado vai ser você que não fez a segurança direito. Você no mínimo precisa avisar formalmente o chefe, gerente ou responsável de que tal e tal ação seriam necessárias e as consequências disso não ser feito. Aí sim, se eles insistirem na solução pior, você pode lavar as mãos deixando todos a par do risco que estão correndo.

Comment: @user2989745 quanto a inserir em outra tabela, basta executar o comando com uma conexão e inserir os dados usando outra. Ou ainda, na hipótese de um usuário com permissão read-only, você poderia dar permissão de escrita apenas para a tabela de saída. Veja, eu atualizei a resposta com alguns detalhes a mais, mas não vou arriscar dar uma lista de palavras porque tenho 100% de certeza que estaria errada e poderia ser minha culpa causar incidentes de segurança  por aí

Comment: agradeço as dicas, concordo contigo quanto a solução. Não é possível definir privilégios ao nível do jdbc ? Por statement ?

Comment: @user2989745 Achei na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxtips.htm#JJDBC28958) uma parte que diz que o driver suporta [conexões read-only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly-boolean-), mas isso é apenas uma otimização e não garante que efeitos colaterais não ocorrerão, por exemplo um `drop table`.